# Elasticsearch: add JSON in historic indices

Tags: json, elasticsearch, indexing, kibana

We currently are importing data using Logstash. One of the fields ("request") is a JSON stored as a string.
We now require a section of this stored JSON as fields in the searchable index. I have updated Logstash filter using

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "request"
        target => "[@metadata][request_json]"
    }
    if [@metadata][request_json][merchant] {
        # in the Request, pull out the Merchant-ID
        mutate {
            add_field => {
                "merchant_id" => "%{[@metadata][request_json][merchant][id]}"
                "merchant_name" => "%{[@metadata][request_json][merchant][name]}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works great for new data.

How can I update the indices for the historic data?
I'm using Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana 8.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Steven I would suggest to create an ingest pipeline performing same operation of extracting the fields and use processors to set those values to the event.

You can then run update_by_query on your old indexes using this pipeline. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.5/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-ingest-pipeline

Comment: Thx @Ayush, I have thought of that. But I can't figure out how to make the "request" a temporary json-field (like in logstash with @metadata). Using Ingest, I believe it would transform "request" into (for example) "request_json", which then would be permanently stored in my Index. And I don't think you can remove a field from an Index once it's stored?

Comment: @Steven you can use the "remove" processors in ingest pipeline to remove the field you don't want to store in the index and probably "dissect" followed by "split" processors can be used to extract the field and values from your request. Make sure you use processors in the same sequence as the event should be manipulated since they are executed sequentially.

Comment: Ah, yes, great, just saw that... now down to Painless scripting which doesn't support JSON... next challenge. Anything you can come up with? Never did "painless"... seems more "painful" to me.

Comment: `now down to Painless scripting which doesn't support JSON` the whole idea of ES is to utilize JSON extensively. What exactly do you have in mind ?
You can hit me up on skype if you wish (ayush.mathur) :)

Comment: Thx @Ayush, Solved, using SET rather than painless
`  { "set": {
      "field": "merchant_name",
      "copy_from": "request_json.merchant.name",
      "override": false,
      "ignore_empty_value": true
    }
  },
...`

Comment: Awesome news, please mark this as solution if everything works fine :)